# Сontext initialized in actual function

Tags: kotlin, multiplatform

I create expect/actual fun create database, but I get error: context has not been initialized
How fix it?

My expect fun:

```
expect fun createDB(): Server?

open class ServerRepository {
    private val database = createDB()
    private val serverQueries = database?.serverQueries

// Insert New Server
fun insert(title: String, url: String, token: String) {
    serverQueries?.insertServer(title, url, token)
}

// Get All Servers
fun list(): List<Servers> {
    return serverQueries?.selectAll()?.executeAsList()!!
}

// Get Server by ID
fun get(id: Long): Query<Servers>? {
    return serverQueries?.selectServer(id)
}

// Update Server
fun update(id: Long, title: String, url: String, token: String) {
    serverQueries?.updateServer(title, url, token, id)
}

// Delete Server
fun delete(id: Long) {
    serverQueries?.deleteServer(id)
}
```

}

Actual:

```
lateinit var context: Context

actual fun createDB() : Server? {
    val driver = AndroidSqliteDriver(Server.Schema, context, "Server.db")
    return Server(driver)
}
```

Error:
**kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property context has not been initialized**

Comment: You have not initialized your context variable before using it.

Comment: I'm just new to kotlin how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is where I find actual/expect doesn't work very well. Actual/Expect lives in your shared code module. Whereas context object (activity/application) live in your platform code module (e.g. androidApp).

Instead of using Actual/Expect, it's simpler to user an interface in your shared code which has an implementation in your platform (where you have access to context objects).